# How to silently fail querySelector() like jQuery() if element does not exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't get this thing right.
Why `jQuery()` outputs an object by default? And is there some way to achieve same result with JavaScript?

```
jQuery('#configurator-material')
init [section#configurator-material.section, context: document, selector: "#configurator-material"]

document.querySelector('#configurator-material');
<section id=​"configurator-material" class=​"section" ng-controller=​"materialCtrl as material">​…​</section>​

document.querySelectorAll('#configurator-material');
NodeList [section#configurator-material.section]
```

In general my problem is that at some point I have this line:

```
jQuery('#myid').addClass('myclass');
```

im trying to replace it with JS like this:

```
document.querySelector('#myid').classList.add('myclass');
```

I thought that it should be fine and without errors,
but i'm getting **"Cannot read property 'classList' of null"** on the JS variant if a specific element does not exists on the page.

Comment: jQuery returns the selected elements wrapped in a jQuery special object (defined by jQuery itself), you won't have the same unless you create a similar object wrapping the elements

Comment: The entire point of jQuery is that it returns an object so you can call methods on it to interact with the element(s) in the DOM. I'm not sure what the problem is, or the point of the question.

Comment: What does console.log() says if you try to get that element? Are you sure DOM is read and  ready? Remember, Undeferred scripts should go before the closing `</body>` tag, not inside head.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan
jQuery('#myid') - console outputs = object. So no problem.
document.querySelector('#myid') - console outputs = 'null'..

Comment: jQuery is forgiving and silently fails. Probably neither jquery nor JS got that element. Because it does not exists or was inexistent at the time the JS interpreter kicked in. jQuery will always return an Object. querySelector will return null.

Comment: You should have mentioned that that element does not actually exists, to make things clearer

Comment: https://gomakethings.com/avoiding-errors-when-using-queryselector-in-vanilla-js/

Comment: Because your vanilla syntax is wrong. You have to check if the target exists applying it. ``document.querySelector('#myid')?.classList.add('myclass');``

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Handling non existent Elements

Internally the **jQuery** library conditionally handles non existent elements - failing silently **without error**.
Take for example a `$("#nonExistent")`, even if the Element is not retrieved in the DOM, the returned value will still be a **jQuery Object instance** - with all its constructor methods available, like `.addClass()` etc.

In contrast, **JavaScript**'s [.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) returns an [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element)  Object, **but** if the element is not found — the primitive **`null` is returned**.
JavaScript will break your code if you try to access *properties* of non-Object. Just like manually writing *`null.classList`* will throw an error:

> ***Uncaught TypeError**: Cannot read properties of null*

### Use JavaScript Optional Chaining `.?`

The simplest way to emulate the similar non-erratic behavior is to use the [Optional Chaining operator `.?`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

```js
// jQuery
$("#notExistent").addClass("red"); // No errors

// JavaScript
document.querySelector("#notExistent")?.classList.add("red"); // No errors
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) if you need to compile your ES6 code in order to support older browsers like i.e: IE (Internet Explorer), or just  use an `if` statement:

```js
// JavaScript
const EL_notExistent = document.querySelector("#notExistent");
if (EL_notExistent) EL_notExistent.classList.add("red"); // No errors
```